# JSON on AsyncTask?

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, httpclient

I'm making an Android program that gets JSON data from the internet. JSON text comes from a source code of a webpage (using HttpClient), then parse it and display it to a TextView. This is working on Froyo but I need it to be on AsyncTask to work on Honeycomb and above.

I'm so confused right now because of this AsyncTask problem. I tried and followed some tutorials but it is different from what I want to do. I just get errors and I'm so frustrated. Thanks for the help! :)

This is my method on the MainActivity class:

```
private void jsonStuffs() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //JSON PARSER & HOME PAGE TEXTVIEWS

            client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            //new Read().execute("id");
            //http client codes only no parser !!
            GetMethodEx test = new GetMethodEx();
            String returned;
            try {
                returned = test.getInternetData();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try{
                String jsonStr = test.getInternetData(); //go to GetMethodEx
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    //find temperature on JSON on webpage
                    String temperature = obj.getString("temperature");
                    TextView tvTemp = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.temp);
                    tvTemp.setText(temperature);

            }
            //catch (JSONException e) {
                 // e.printStackTrace();
                //} 
            catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
```

This is my GetMethodEx class:

```
public class GetMethodEx extends Activity {
public String getInternetData() throws Exception{

    BufferedReader in = null;
    String data = null;
    //

    try{
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        URI website = new URI("http://nhjkv.comuf.com/json_only.php");
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.setURI(website);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String l = "";
        String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((l = in.readLine()) !=null){
            sb.append(l + nl);
        }
        in.close();
        data = sb.toString();
        return data;
    }finally {
        if (in !=null){
            try{
                in.close();
                return data;
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: For example, I tried putting this code below the AsyncTask class declaration
  `TextView tvTemp = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);`,
I'm getting an error `The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type loadSomeStuff`. And if I put it on the onCreate method, It doesn't work. It says the tvtemp cannot be resolved on onPostExecute().I understand a bit of the logic of AsyncTask but I'm not that good in Java coding.

Comment: @KkeevvSienaAlejandrino : see my answer and make AsyncTask inner class of Activity instead of Creating it in separate file and if you want to create it in separate file then pass Activity Context to it

Answer (score 1):

Make your connection part as a seperate class and put the below code in it

```
public String getInternetData() throws Exception{

BufferedReader in = null;
String data = null;
//

try{
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    URI website = new URI("http://nhjkv.comuf.com/json_only.php");
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
    request.setURI(website);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
    String l = "";
    String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    while ((l = in.readLine()) !=null){
        sb.append(l + nl);
    }
    in.close();
    data = sb.toString();
    return data;
}finally {
    if (in !=null){
        try{
            in.close();
            return data;
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Use this class as your service

```
public class TaskAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

private String response = null;

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    response = new ClassName().getInternetData();
    return response;
}

}
```

then put this in your activity

```
String response = new TaskAsync().execute("URL_WITH_PARAMETERS").get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Chnage your code as for making  webserivce call using AsyncTask :

```
private void jsonStuffs() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try{

               new InternetDataOperation().execute("");

            }
            //catch (JSONException e) {
                 // e.printStackTrace();
                //} 
            catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

private class InternetDataOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

      @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {
      }

      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        GetMethodEx test = new GetMethodEx();
        String jsonStr = test.getInternetData(); //go to GetMethodEx
            return jsonStr;
      }      

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(String result) {  
         JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result);

         //find temperature on JSON on webpage
         String temperature = obj.getString("temperature");
         TextView tvTemp = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.temp);
         tvTemp.setText(temperature);             
      }


}
```

Comment: I get an error on `test` on the jsonStuffs() method `test cannot be resolved`. I tried making it all public but it doesn't work. I get another two errors below but I think it was only because of that `test` error.

Comment: @KkeevvSienaAlejandrino : see my edit answer and no need to use test.getInternetData(); line in  jsonStuffs() method because we have moved it inside doInBackground of AsyncTask

Comment: It says surround with with try&catch so I do this, Is this right?  `protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    GetMethodEx test = new GetMethodEx();
    String jsonStr;
 try {
  jsonStr = test.getInternetData();
     return jsonStr;
 } catch (Exception e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
 } //go to GetMethodEx
 return null;
    
  }`

Now the only error I get is on jsonStr on the : `onPostExecute(String result) {  
     JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);` It says it cannot be resolved to a variable.

Comment: @KkeevvSienaAlejandrino : sorry friend just  typing mistake use `JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result);` instead of `JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);`

Comment: I surround It also with try/catch and I didn't get any errors now. Now I am getting force close dialog. I tried setting `jsonStr`,`obj`,`temperature`,`tvTemp` as global variabe but It still force closing

Answer (score 1):

You can't use findViewByID and textView inside doInBackground method. You can use textView in onPostExecute.

Modify method "jsonStuffs()" so that return String. And you dont have to put getInternetData() to another activity class.

Its modified methods from your MainActivity.class

```
private String jsonStuffs() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //JSON PARSER & HOME PAGE TEXTVIEWS

            client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            //new Read().execute("id");
            //http client codes only no parser !!

            String returned;
            try {
                returned = getInternetData();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try{
                String jsonStr = test.getInternetData(); //go to GetMethodEx
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    //find temperature on JSON on webpage
                    String temperature = obj.getString("temperature");
                    return temperature

            }
            //catch (JSONException e) {
                 // e.printStackTrace();
                //} 
            catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
        }

public String getInternetData() throws Exception{

    BufferedReader in = null;
    String data = null;
    //

    try{
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        URI website = new URI("http://nhjkv.comuf.com/json_only.php");
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.setURI(website);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String l = "";
        String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((l = in.readLine()) !=null){
            sb.append(l + nl);
        }
        in.close();
        data = sb.toString();
        return data;
    }finally {
        if (in !=null){
            try{
                in.close();
                return data;
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

and then create asynctask like this:

```
public class JsonDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return jsonStuff()
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        if(result != null){
            //DO YOUR STUFF WITH TEXTVIEW
        }
    }

}
```

You need to initialize textView within onCreate() or onResume() method in MainActivity.class